# What's the difference between і and ТА?

Tags: вживання-слів

I have noticed that in Ukrainian two words represent the word 'and' in English. Is there any rule that explains when to use **і** and when to use **ТА**?

Answer (score 2):

***I*** and ***TA*** are synonyms and usualy mean ***AND*** but they aren't quite the same.
***I*** tends to connect equal things or events which can be any member of the sentence or any clause. (***AND***)
*Я люблю яблука і груші. - I like apples and pears (simultaneously).*
***TA*** is mostly about adding something extra. There is a main thing or event and there is additional one which joins the main. (***ALSO***)
*Я люблю яблука та груші. - I like apples and (also) pears (but I prefer apples).*
Besides ***TA*** can join the information that is opposite but ***I*** cannot. (***BUT***)
*Я люблю яблука, та наразі вони скінчилися. - I like apples but they've just ended.*
But ***I*** can be doubled unlike ***TA*** which can't. (***BOTH... AND...***)
*Я люблю і яблука, і груші. - I like both apples and pears.*

Answer (score 0):

Word I and TA, as well as Й have the same meaning and are used to avoid tautology.
In some dialects and internet culture ТА can also mean YES (as short for TAK).

Comment: ТА can also mean BUT. I.e. it has two (or three) meanings: AND, BUT (and also YES in some dialects).